# Can I use http instead of https?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

The following is an extract from [Google Cast Developer Setup](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting):

"Good Receiver URL's usually look like https://website.com/rcvr/myreceiver.html or https://website.com/qarcvr/myreceiver.html"

Question is can I use 'http://website.com/rcvr/myreceiver.html'  instead of 'https://website.com/rcvr/myreceiver.html'  for the receiver URL?

Comment: Yes, if you want NSA to listen to it

Comment: NSA is going to be able to listen to it either way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can; it is up to you to decide. For certain apps, there is no reason to use https. If, however, you choose to use "https", you need to make sure that the certificates are valid and the root is known (i.e, do not use a self-signed certificate).

Comment: Wait, is this from an actual engineer working on the device? Man I love StackOverflow :)